# How to get AntD Table to display nested dataSource data

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have a nested data structure that starts with the idea that you have multiple tenants. Each tenant can have multiple applicants. Each applicant has data associated with it (first name, last name, etc). It looks like this:

[image]

and i'm currently using an AntD Table tag that looks like this (but doesn't work. it displays nothing):

```
<Table rowKey="firstName" dataSource={this.props.tenants[0].applicants} columns={this.columns} pagination={false} footer={() => ""} />
```

And the columns data structure looks like this:

```
columns = [
  {
    title: "First",
    dataIndex: "firstName",
    key: "firstName",
    render: (text) => <a>{text}</a>
  },
  {
    title: "Last",
    dataIndex: "lastName",
    key: "lastName",
    render: (text) => <a>{text}</a>
  }
]
```

The problem I'm having is that I want to create an AntD table where i display the data for only the first applicant for each Tenant. So specifically, John Doe for tenant 0 and Steve Middlefield for tenant 1. How do I do this? i.e. how do i pass a dataSource that would display a row for each applicant[0] within the tenants array?

Put another way, my data structure doesn't conform to the way AntD wants it's dataSource passed. I assume that I need to pass it a dataSource that does. i.e. that only represents the first applicant from each tenant in my nested array. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do this

> I want to create an AntD table where i display the data for only the
> first applicant for each Tenant. So specifically, John Doe for tenant
> 0 and Steve Middlefield for tenant 1

you need to map on your tenants and get only the first applicants

```
//get first applicants of each tenant only
const firstApplicants = tenants.map((tenant) => tenant.applicants[0]);
```

it will return one dimentional array that looks like this

```
[
   {firstName: "", lastName: ""},
   {firstName: "", lastName: ""}
]
```

then you can use that array on dataSource of the `Table`

```
<Table dataSource={firstApplicants} />
```

see working code here:

[image: Edit prod-http-h73fi]

Comment: That worked perfectly. Is there an appropriate way to inject a key when creating firstApplicants rather then using firstName as the key? Seems like a bad idea to use firstName as the rowkey.

Comment: while looping, you can inject an index (counter) as a key if for displaying purposes but not a good practice/idea if you will perform add, edit or delete on it. Better to inlcude an applicant_id